# Cannot get a JSON response using Python request

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a product webpage where I get **after I login**, product description and characteristics

https://www.questonline.gr/proionta/laptop,-tablet-axesouar/laptop/nb-dell-inspiron-3552-n3060-4gb-500gb-w10

But it displays the prices using a JSON file coming from a different URL https://www.questonline.gr/quest-mvc/Pricing/GetPrices

I use the following part:

```
time.sleep(3)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}

r = self.ses.get(myurl, headers=headers)


if r.status_code == 200:

    r2 = self.ses.post('https://www.questonline.gr/quest-mvc/Pricing/GetPrices')
    json_data = json.loads(r2.text)
    print(json_data)

    Myhtml = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Myhtml, 'html.parser')
```

The JSON response I want to get is

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "item_list": {
    "263704": {
      "Matnr": "263704",
      "Price": 21.12,
      "Price1": 0.0,
      "Price2": 0.0,
      "Currency": "EUR"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]
Instead I get an error like:

{'error': 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.','debug': ''}

If I change to get.(url) I get error

expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 6)

So can I get Price from JSON response?

Is it wrong to do it by post and not by get?

Is it wrong that I insert headers?

Thank you and sorry for my novice questions

Comment: You are passing what looks like a user agent string, not a content type.

Comment: I changed it to User-Agent and I get the same error

Comment: Since it's a post request, it most likely expects something to be sent in the body.

Comment: Shouldnt I put post I changed it from get because of headers tab in chrome I thought it wrong way?

Comment: If you can only view the details after login, you may need to pass authentication credentials, either in the POST body, in an authorization header or as an HTTP cookie.

Comment: @bjmc But I do the get or the post like self.session.post(..) so all the credentials arent there?

Comment: Maybe! It's hard to tell without more context of your code. What is 'self' here? What do you have stored in 'session'? It's possible it's automatically passing the cookie for you.

Comment: @bjmc The self is because of class method, Initialy though is the structure and the order of commands correct? if skunumber is passed through header in which format should be?

Comment: You'd have to look at the browser debug console and see what headers and/or POST body parameters are being passed. The format is likely specific to this particular website/API.